# GPS doesn´t work in IntentService

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have the following code in my Service:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = 
         (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = 
          locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getName();
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    while(true)
     {
       if(...)//every 5 seconds it gets into
         {
                ....//control if the location is not null
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();
            alt = location.getAltitude();
            Log.i(TAG, "Latitude: "+lat+"\nLongitude: "+lon+"\nAltitude: "+alt);

         }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error!");
            }
    }
```

This code kind of works in my emulator (GPS are inserted into the `Log`), but in my Mobile device, this code gets to the `else` branch. Could somebody tell me where is the problem? In my code or in my Mobile device? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: The GPS is turned on, in another apps it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` will not fetch subsequent location from the GPS provider. It will return (as the name may suggest) the last known location requested by some code. I assume that you check location being not `null` in the condition, which is not shown in your code. The location is null if the device "decided" that the last known location is too old or unreliable by other means.  You need to request location updates and provide a location listener to get locations repeatetly.

There are lots of tutorials available. [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html) ist one. of them.

Comment: Thanks, but I have one question. If I create a LocationListener (Activity), using your tutorial, will it continue doing it´s task also if the screen turn off or somebody calls?

Comment: The LocationListener does not need to be an activity. Its just some class implementing the LocationListener interface. It will working if the screens turns off or somebody calls (if you are interacting with some activity it will not be visible, of course). However, if the CPU powers down, you won't get more updates. To prevent the latter, you need to get a WakeLock which prevents the CPU from being turned off.

Comment: So, if I create only f.ex. `public class MyClass implements LocationListener`, this class will be running also in these cases I´ve described?

Comment: Yes, unless the phone stops the CPU (which it will do some time after the screen went black, see WakeLock remark in my comment, if you need to know more about WakeLocks search for them in this forum!).